# USRP Overflow Detected and FFT scale

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I've read this is no big deal but it's really annoying.  I'm plotting a 40Mhz BW at 20MSPS.  This is a N210 and I'm connected through a switch.
It seems to plot fine but the scale on the Y-axis is constantly changing. Can I fix this?

Finally, the X-axis is from 0 to 500e-3.  This makes no sense to me given my settings. Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: What version of the IDE are you using?  Are you plotting the time domain data or frequency domain?  If frequency domain, are you using the "Plot FFT" feature from the IDE or do you have a PSD component doing the conversion?

Comment: I was doing the Plot FFT from within the sandbox.  This was a plot of the raw data coming in.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the question, "It seems to plot fine but the scale on the Y-axis is constantly changing. Can I fix this?" you can bring up the plot menu using the small down arrow on the plot view. From there select Settings... and under the Plot section there are places for the plot min and max, which default to AUTO.

Answer (score 0):

> USRP Overflow detected; I've read this is no big deal ...

It **really** is a big deal. It means your PC was not fast enough at processing the samples that came from the USRP, so some samples had to be dropped. This is the worst that can happen to your signal.

You will need to make your signal processing faster (for example, instead of processing everything live first storing things to an SSD and then later process stuff offline, or buy a significantly faster PC, if you think that would help with your specific application), or reduce the sampling rate.

> I'm plotting a 40Mhz BW at 20MSPS

Nyquist says you're not. You can't observe 40 MHz bandwidth with 20 MS/s, it's mathematically impossible.

> It seems to plot fine but the scale on the Y-axis is constantly changing. Can I fix this?

I don't know the graphical sinks of redhawk, but this sounds like autoscaling, so yes, probably you can disable that feature.

> Finally, the X-axis is from 0 to 500e-3. This makes no sense to me given my settings. Can someone please help me understand this?

You don't tell us *what* you're plotting. Time values, given some trigger, converting complex samples to their magnitude? Or is it some kind of power spectrum?

In the later case, this is most probably normalized frequency for a real signal; you have to read it as "frequency in units of sampling rate".

Comment: Many good points.  As you can tell I have no experience with Redhawk or things like GNU-Radio.  Some of the relationships between variables still elude me.  I'm honestly just trying to build a simple FM receiver to start with and will then move to FSK stuff.     My PC should be fine, i7 with SSD.  Is there any documentation that covers what these variables actually mean?

Comment: Well, the documentation you're asking for would be an introduction to digital signal processing; the GNU Radio project has compiled a nice list of recommended readings; maybe start with michael Ossmann's introduction: https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/SuggestedReading

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully this will help.  I've worked with SDR before, just very custom ones that aren't graphical.  I'll give it a go.